# Saving VB Script Templates in SDL Tridion adds "dirty" characters

Tags: tridion

I have a really weird problem with SDL Tridion 2009 and I hope someone has already experienced it. Sometimes (not everytime) when I modify and then "save&close" my PageTemplates or ComponentTemplates I then have compilation errors due to strange characters automatically added (I don't know when and I don't know by "who") to the code.
In example, one of the most usual is "`".
Anyone has ideas?

Thank you anyway

Comment: Are you copying your code from somewhere, or just typing?

Comment: You mention components  in the title, and then page and component templates in the text. Is it just templates, or components also? Perhaps you can also explain what kind of templates you are using. Are these old school VBScript templates, or modulate templates, or are they actually TBBs etc.

Comment: +1 on copy pasting from somewhere.  The backwards quote is a classic MS Word transformation.

Comment: I'm just writing code (old VBScript), I've never made cut & paste. I have this problem in PTs and CTs, I've mentioned components in the title only for sake of shortness. :)

Comment: Could you clarify where these characters appear (in the Source tab? top, bottom, anywhere?) 
Is it literally preventing you from saving the templates? 
Do you have any extensions installed that might be interfering?

Comment: So, are when you save the CT or PT and you re-open it the characters appear? Or do they only show up when rendering or previewing?